# Getting p-values from a mixed-effect ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I'm struggling to extract F-values and/or p-values from an ANOVA with all random effects or an ANOVA with both mixed and random effects.

I would expect to be able to get F- and p-values regarding the variance of the random effects based on the expected mean squares. Maybe the  `aov()` function just doesn't return what I'm looking for? Or I'm specifying my model incorrectly?

Here's a simple example where I want to have `cyl` as a fixed effect and `carb` as a random effect:

```
data(mtcars)
summary(aov(formula = mpg ~ cyl + Error(carb), data = mtcars))
```

But no p-values for the random effect are reported.

```
Error: carb
    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
cyl  1  341.8   341.8

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
cyl        1  492.1   492.1   48.85 1.1e-07 ***
Residuals 29  292.2    10.1                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics

Comment: I think this question relates enough to the structure of ANOVA objects in R to remain here.

Comment: You really ought to post the output. I think a p-value _is_ reported, even though I question whether it should be. What do you think that `Pr(>F)` is doing there. (Agree should be closed. No programming issues here. Just a need for further statistical education.)

Comment: You do not get $p$-values of a random effect generally speaking. You can test its significant with a LR-test using a mixture of $\chi^2$ distributions (Self & Liang, 1987) but I wouldn't recommended it. Information criteria (AIC, BIC, etc.), or (parametric?) bootstrapping probably will get you further.